# {Status: 202} when running a lambda from code

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

This is my code in Javascript:

```
    var params = {
        FunctionName: "theTable",
        InvokeArgs: JSON.stringify({ "name": "KirklandWA" })
    };
    lambda.invokeAsync(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

This is in Lambda:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return "theReturnedValue";
};
```

What is happening is that it is not returning the `theReturnedValue`, instead returns

> {Status: 202}
>   Status: 202

The code in `Lambda` is getting invoked, I made sure of it at `Cloudwatch`.

Comment: Can you run the lambda test successfully in the lambda console? If so it should say success and "theReturnedValue" as a response. if it is successful in running within the test console then your problem probably lies within the API Gateway.

Comment: @NicoLA the problem is `invokeAsync()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that your `lambda function` is not returning anything back to the caller.

Your handle funtion has a third parameter which is a callback function that is used to return results to the caller.

The `callback` function takes in two values, an Error and results

```
callback(Error error, Object result);
```

If you provide the Error values the lambda will throw the an error you provide to the user, if you dont provide an Error value but the results, its the results that will be returned

Its all documented very well [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html)

Here are basic examples

```
callback();     // Indicates success but no information returned to the caller.
callback(null); // Indicates success but no information returned to the caller.
callback(null, "success");  // Indicates success with information returned to the caller.
callback(error);    //  Indicates error with error information returned to the caller.
```

Your handler function should be.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context,callback) => {
     callback(null, "theReturnedValue");
};
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The problem is that the lambda is invoked with `invokeAsync` which is just an alias for invoking the function with invocation type `Event` and not `RequestResponse`. This is, as the name suggests, an asyncronous invocation which is "fire-and-forget", i.e., it does not carry back any response. Use `RequestResponse` instead to get a synchronous invocation where a result is carried back. Other answers deal with this fact as well, but the accepted answer does not.

Answer (score 13):

You're invoking with `invokeAsync` which will only return status code as stated in the documentation. Use `invoke` with `InvocationType: "RequestResponse"` instead

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

```
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({});
var params = {
  FunctionName: "function_name", 
  InvocationType: "RequestResponse"
};
response = lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: My two cents - invokeAsync has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your lambda this selected as NodeJs 8.10 runtime, once having verified you must return a promise directly:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve({ message: "hello world" });
    });
};
```

I was looking invokeAsync method definition in the [aws-sdk documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invokeAsync-property) and the status code is fine:

> **Callback parameters:**
>
> 1. err (Error) — the error object returned from the request. Set to null if the request is successful.
> 2. data (Object) — the de-serialized data returned from the request. Set to null if a request error occurs. The data object has the
>      following properties:
>
>    - Status — (Integer) It will be **202** upon success.

I prepare you a basic example, please review **handler.js** file:

```
https://github.com/ns4lin4s/stackoverflow
```

Dont forget, that you must specify response body:

[image]

So when you finish, let me know how that works!

Comment: Nope, same result. I am receiving `202`, but no other data I want to return.

Comment: where are calling this lambda from? i'm supposing that you have an api and this api is calling another lambda, anyway you must specify the response data, above there is an image. please if is not work, give me more details.. i hope to help you